# Define variable in LaTeX with value contain mathematical operator

Tags: variable, def

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{book}
\begin{document}
    \def\s{(1/(2+sqrt(2)))}
    \s
\end{document}
```

I want make a variable `\s` with the value `1/(2+sqrt(2))`. LaTeX cannot automatically compute `\s` as `0.29289321881`. How to define variable in LaTeX with value contain mathematical operator/ mathematical function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to use `\fpeval`, so

```
\edef\s{\fpeval{(1/(2+sqrt(2)))}}
```

will store

```
0.2928932188134525
```

in `\s`.

However, if you have many of such constants, the naming becomes important: for instance you should not have `\c` as one of them, because you'd be redefining a basic LaTeX commands and may get very weird errors. A general rule is *not* to use `\def` unless you precisely know that the command you're defining is not already existing.

I suggest to use a sort of namespace.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% constant store
\NewDocumentCommand{\CS}{mm}
 {% #1 = name, #2 = value
  \ongky_constant_store:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

% constant use
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\UC}{m}
 {% #1 = name
  \ongky_constant_use:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \ongky_constant_store:nn
 {
  \fp_gzero_new:c { g_ongky_constant_#1_fp }
  \fp_gset:cn { g_ongky_constant_#1_fp } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \ongky_constant_use:n
 {
  \fp_use:c { g_ongky_constant_#1_fp }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\CS{s}{(1/(2+sqrt(2)))}

\begin{document}

\UC{s}

\fpeval{(1/\UC{s}-2)^2}

\end{document}
```

[image]